# Convert camelCase to dash-case (hypens) in pure ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

There are plenty of posts about the opposite way.

But how to I convert `camelCase` to `camel-case` in ruby? My regex-game is pretty low ... here is it the other way around:

```
def underscore(string)
  string.gsub(/::/, '/').
  gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1_\2').
  gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1_\2').
  tr("-", "_").
  downcase
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ActiveRecord already has it:

```
gem install i18n activesupport-inflector
```

then

```
require 'active_support/inflector'
"myHTMLComponent".underscore.dasherize
# => "my-html-component"
```

You can see the implementation [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/14931e537f3dcd522b68a5b640aa47272602a137/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb) (with `acronym_underscore_regex` [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/14931e537f3dcd522b68a5b640aa47272602a137/activesupport/lib/active_support/inflector/inflections.rb)).

If you don't want to worry about corner cases like acronyms, this should suffice:

```
"myCamelCase".gsub(/[[:upper:]]/) { "-#{$&.downcase}" }
# => "my-camel-case"
```

Answer (score -1):

here it is:

```
def to_dash_case(string)
  string.gsub(/::/, '/').
  gsub(/([A-Z]+)([A-Z][a-z])/,'\1-\2').
  gsub(/([a-z\d])([A-Z])/,'\1-\2').
  downcase
end
```

not that complicated after all ...

Comment: That won’t work with allowed UTF-8 alphanumeric subset like `Λμ` or `Фы`. Whether you are fine with latin subset only, use ruby built-in `underscore`.